# Should you use bootstrap.css + normalize.css at the same time?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've read that bootstrap.css already includes a version of the code from normalize.css, so is it redundant to use both files?

In other words, if I am using bootstrap do I not need to use normalize.css? Or should I use both files to thoroughly ensure cross-browser compatibility?

Answer (score 5):

Bootstrap *does* have normalize.css included, so it would be redundant to include it elsewhere.

[Bootstrap's documentation on normalize.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#overview-normalize)

Bootstrap 4 (Beta) uses [Reboot](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/reboot/), which builds on Normalize, which would also make including it elsewhere redundant.